# Need to add text before the last listed category and then at the end of it. (Wordpress category php)

Tags: php

I've caught a snag with a set up that I'm hoping to achieve in my php code. This code pulls the categories that listings are grouped in to and displays it in the screen as such:

Featured in **Home Cooking**, **Fresh Fruits**, **Dinner**, **Quick Meals**

What I'm hoping to achieve is this:

Featured in **Home Cooking**, **Fresh Fruits**, **Dinner** and **Quick Meals** Collections

If you take notice, the *and* before the word Quick Meals and the *Collections* after it are the changes I need made. I'm just starting to learn php, and I can't make this adjustment without breaking it. Here is what I'm working with:

Many thanks if you are able to save me from this. I'd imagine it's nothing too difficult.

```
$permalink = get_permalink( $id );
```

$seo = get_the_title()." - offers: ";

$Category_links = ' Featured in ';

$term_list_category = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'listings_categories', array("fields" => "ids"));

$i = 0;

$count = count($term_list_category);

```
if ( $count > 0 ){

    foreach ( $term_list_category as $term_category ) {

        $thisCat = get_term_by( 'id', $term_category, 'listings_categories');

        $url = '<a class="listing-links" href="/listings/'.$thisCat->{'slug'}.'/'.'" title="'.$thisCat->{'name'}.' - Food listings " >'.$thisCat->{'name'}.'</a>';

        $i ++;

        $seo .= " " . $thisCat->{'name'} . "";

        $Category_links .= " " . $url . "";

        if ($count > 1 && $count !== $i) {$Category_links .= ", ";  $seo .= ", "; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below this line ---> $Category_links .= " " . $url . "";

Change the code to...

```
        if($count-1 == $i){
            $Category_links .= " and ";  $seo .= ", ";
        }elseif($count > 1 && $count !== $i){
            $Category_links .= ", ";  $seo .= ", "; 
        }

    }
    $Category_links .= " Collections";      
}
```

Basically you are checking to see if you are at the next to last element in the array ($count-1) and inserting an " and " instead of a ", "

Then outside the loop you can add $Category_links .= " Collections"; to add to the end of the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer simple array manipulation for string output;

**Basic**

```
//example of assigning those categories
$cats = array('Cat 1', 'Cat 2', 'Cat 3', 'Cat 4');
$ccats = count($cats);

foreach($cats as $i => $cat)
{
    //apply slug as needed here     
    $cats[$i] = '<a href="">' . $cat . '</a>';  
    if($i < ($ccats-1))
    {
        $cats[$i] .= ',';
    }
}

array_splice($cats, ($ccats-1), 0, array('and'));

$cats[] = ' Collections';

echo implode($cats, ' ');
```

**Implementation (untested)**

```
$cats = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'listings_categories', array("fields" => "ids"));
$ccats = count($cats);
$vcats = array();

foreach($cats as $i => $cat)
{
    //apply slug & name as needed here  
    $vcats[$i] = '<a class="listing-links" href="/listing/' . $cat->slug . '" title="' . $cat->name . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';

    if($i < ($ccats-1))
    {
        $vcats[$i] .= ',';
    }
}

array_splice($vcats, ($ccats-1), 0, array('and'));

echo 'Featured in ' . implode($vcats, ' ') . ' Collections';
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Ryan, really appreciate the answer. Going to look into this more in depth later. The other answer worked out quickly for me.